# CKeditor 5 Background Color Change

Tags: themes, ckeditor5

So im looking to change the background colour of the text area on CKeditor5, iv tried doing it inline, using a css file but it doesn't respond.

I found this guide
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/ui/theme-customization.html

But I don't understand what its saying? or feel its telling me where and how to implement this. Is anyone aware of a working demo of this or could show me how to do it?

Thanks for any help in advance - Greg

Comment: Please share your code!  we can't solve it without code

Comment: It’s a bog standard ckeditor5, and I don’t understand the guide on how to change the background colour and was hoping someone would explain the guide to me?